# Convention to remove CascadeOnDelete

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to remove some CascadeOnDelete markes from a ForeignKey Relationship in special cases.

The case is if one end of the relationship is a specific type and the other end is not, then I want to set cascadeOnDelete to false.

```
class CascadeOnDeleteSuppressionConvention : IConceptualModelConvention<AssociationType>, IConvention
{
  public void Apply(AssociationType associationType, DbModel model)
  {
    if(!associationType.IsForeignKey)
        return;

    if(associationType.AssociationEndMembers[0].GetPOCOType() == typeof(someType) &&
       associationType.AssociationEndMembers[1].GetPOCOType() != typeof(someTypeOtherType))
         associationType.AssociationEndMembers[0].DeleteAction = DeleteAction.None;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I have no clue how to get the POCO-Type from the Code-First Model.
Can someone provide information on how to get that type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to get a mapping between the EntityType from the ConceptualModel and the CLRType from my application.

Inside the `ConceptualModel.EntityTypes` is Metadata available, which suits my needs here:

```
public EntityType FindEntityType(DbModel model, Type type)
{
    var const metadataPropertyName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation:ClrType";

    var entityType = model.ConceptualModel.EntityTypes.SingleOrDefault(
        e => e.MetadataProperties.Contains(metadataPropertyName) &&
             e.MetadataProperties.GetValue(metadataPropertyName).Value as Type == type
        );

    return entityType;
}
```

That code snipped can be used to get the necessary information and check if the EntityType matches.

The EntityType to ClrType Code

```
public Type GetClrType(EntityType entityType)
{
    const string metadataPropertyName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation:ClrType";

    MetadataProperty metadataProperty;
    if (entityType.MetadataProperties.TryGetValue(metadataPropertyName, true, out metadataProperty))
        return metadataProperty.Value as Type;

    return null;
}
```